# How to save Date from Windows Form to SQL Server when Culture is "ar-KW"

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-2008

I have multi language application where i am using "en-US" and "ar-KW" languages.
I also have WinForm where I am using the DateTimePicker control.
When the user logs in, if his default language is "en-US" it saves the record but when he has default language "ar-KW" then this date format is not saving in database, and produces an error. Why?

The datatype of the Employee DateOfBirth field is `smallDateTime` in SQL Server.
I am using the following code in VB to save the record. There is a normal `INSERT` stored procedure in the backend.

```
If Me.dtDateOfBirth.Checked = False Then
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@DateOfBirth", SqlDbType.SmallDateTime).Value = SqlDateTime.Null
Else
        If mUserDefaultLanguage = "ar-KW" Then
                Me.dtDateOfBirth.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
                Me.dtDateOfBirth.CustomFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
                Dim oDate As String = Me.dtDateOfBirth.Text
                Dim dt As Date
                dt = (CType(oDate, Date))
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@DateOfBirth", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = SqlDateTime.Parse(dt)
        Else
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@DateOfBirth", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = SqlDateTime.Parse(Me.dtDateOfBirth.Text)
        End If

End If
```

Comment: Error No: 5  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breadkConnection)...............................................................................................................System.Data.SqlClient.SqlComman.InternalExecuteNonQuery(dbAsync Result result, STring methodName, Boolean senToPipe) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlComman.ExecuteNonQuery()

Comment: The good stuff is in the `.Errors` property of the SqlException. Capture that - I bet it'll make the problem clear.

Comment: It dosent' showing any specific details of error even i have change the datatype in SQL Server 2008 to DateTime and then DateTime2(7) but still the same error...........when i save with culuture "en-US" it save the date but when i try to save with "ar-KW" it give error.

Comment: Is there *anything* in `Errors`?

Answer (score 0):

This could be the problem with datetime conversion:

```
    Dim oDate As String = Me.dtDateOfBirth.Text
    Dim dt As Date
    dt = (CType(oDate, Date))
```

Why don't you make use of `.Value` property of `DateTimePicker` control, rather than converting its `.Text` property to `DateTime` type?